# IntelliJ IDEA mouse over method show Java Doc

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 9, Is there a way to configure IDEA so that when I pause my mouse over a method, IDEA pulls up the javadoc (the same thing as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> does)?

Comment: It seems this feature may be going into IntelliJ IDEA 12.1 or 12.1.x, finally.... http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66333#comment=27-462576

Comment: IntelliJ 2018.2.4 (Community Edition):               
`Preferences > Editor > General: Other (subsection) > Show quick documentation on mouse move`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such feature right now, feel free to vote for the [existing enhancement request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5999).

As stated in the comments, one can write a plug-in that will add this functionality.

**Edit**
Since this is the first hit on Google about this I would like to add that Edolsa's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461740/2135787) is the correct solution as of January 2014.

Comment: I guess the enhancements would go into v10 ...

Comment: @Chris, IDEA 10 is already current version with no new features planned, IDEA 11 will be released in a couple of months from now and this feature is not in the roadmap. What is your guess based on?

Comment: Lol - good point, bad guess- I didn't see an 11 EAP , so I went for 10 :)

Comment: Right... well, the project I'm on for which I have to use IDEA will probably not last *that* long and I can go back to Eclipse after that. Thanks, I'll submit the feature request though. Does the enhancement request work like a voting system that features with the most votes get implemented?

Comment: Requests that have more votes have more chances to be addressed faster.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Is there any option to make mouse hover behave like i pressed ctrl+p ? ( show method signature ( without holding ctrl) ?

Answer (score 48):

Just to update, IntelliJ 13.0 is now released and has this feature.

Location in 13.0:

> Preferences -> Editor -> Other -> "Show quick doc on mouse move"

Location in 13.1 (and later):

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> "Other" section -> "Show quick documentation on mouse move"

You can even set the hover time (in ms) and once the doc pane opens, you can Pin it to one of the sides and it becomes one of the windows, like Console or Terminal. This is very handy, as you just over over and look at the pinned window.

Comment: this is the correct answer as of now, thank you very much!

Comment: In my IntelliJ 13.1 Ultimate, it's at File -> Settings -> Editor, there is a check box called "show quick doc on mouse move"

Comment: In my IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2, it's at Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Other (subsection, not tab) -> "Show quick documentation on mouse move"

Answer (score 7):

There is a setting under Preferences -> Editor -> Show quick doc on mouse move, but I've found it's completely unusable. It shows the quick doc for all variables so when you're hovering over to find out what a variable's value is the quick doc blocks it. Also most of the time the doc is collapsed and it's a pain to get to the right hand corner without it disappearing to expand it. Needs work, doesn't work nearly as well as it did in Eclipse.

Comment: This comment was made a little less than 2 years ago, and this stuff still continues to happen. It's these little things that make my hate the Android team for switching to Android Studio more reasonable as time goes on.

Comment: I'm noticing the documentation is collapsed on hover too. The hover window shows up, but only shows the package. If i "Pin" that hover window, then I can see the documentation. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm migrating to Android Studio. I miss this Eclipse feature too.

I created a new shourtcut for *Quick documentation* command: **Alt + Left click**

(*Preferences -> Keymap -> Quick documentation*)

It seems comfortable and gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Add to idea.properties the following line and restart Intellij

```
auto.show.quick.doc=true
```