# Intellisense issue with intelliJIDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellisense

I'm switching from Flash Builder to IDEA, and I've find that there is something I don't have, that is the ability to see the method annotations (/** **/) when you hover over it. I didn't find a way to do it, I just can't see any info regarding that.

Any IDEAs?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, this is not really insellisense related, anyway the solution is this:

"File -> Settings -> Editor, there is a check box called "show quick doc on mouse move""

Found it here: [IntelliJ IDEA mouse over method show Java Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739251/intellij-idea-mouse-over-method-show-java-doc)